# Is it easy to prove that for any $n$, $f^k(n)= 4$ for some $k$ or $f^k(n)= 1$ for some $k$ holds? (Mathematica book by Roozbeh Hazrat)

Tags: mathematica

I am reading "Mathematica: A Problem-Centered Approach Second Edition" by Roozbeh Hazrat.

The following problem is Problem 8.13 on p. 137:

> A happy number is a number such that if one squares its digits and adds
> them together, and then takes the result and squares its digits and adds them
> together again and keeps doing this process, one comes down to the number $1$.
> Find all the happy ages, i.e., happy numbers up to $100$.

The author's answer is the following:

`Select[Range[100], NestWhile[Plus @@ (IntegerDigits[#]^2)&, #, (!#==4) && (!#==1)&] == 1&]`

---

Let $f$ be the following function:
`f[n_] := Apply[Plus, IntegerDigits[n]^2];`

The author assumes that for any $n$, $f^k(n)= 4$ for some $k$ or $f^k(n)= 1$ for some $k$ holds.
But the author didn't write that this property holds in the above book.
I wonder why the author didn't write that this property holds.

Is it easy to prove that for any $n$, $f^k(n)= 4$ for some $k$ or $f^k(n)= 1$ for some $k$ holds?

I checked the following holds:
$f(4)=16\neq 1, f(16)=37\neq 1, f(37)=58\neq 1, f(58)=89\neq 1, f(89)=145\neq 1, f(145)=42\neq 1, f(42)=20\neq 1, f(20)=4.$
And obviously $f(1)=1$.

If you know a proof of the above property, please tell me the proof.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4208465/42969

Comment: @MartinR Thank you very much for your link. I think this property is not easy to prove. I think the author should write this property holds with or without a proof.

Answer (score 1):

Martin R, Thank you very much for your [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4208465/384082).

I checked if $1\leq n\leq 279$, then $f^k(n)=4$ for some $k$ or $f^k(n)=1$ for some $k$ holds:

Input:
`f[n_] := Apply[Plus, IntegerDigits[n]^2];`
`g[n_] := !((n == 1) || (n == 4));`
`h[n_] := NestWhile[f, n, g];`
`Map[h, Range[279]]`

The above code terminated.